# How to make a Stepwise Regression function which runs fine on a single csv run on a folder full of csvs using lapply?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to run/fit an individual Backward Elimination Stepwise Regression on each of N csv files (which are all in the same file folder called "sample_obs" where my N = 47,000 csvs, but I am sure the answer will work for any N csvs in the same folder). I am using the step() function from the stats package.

Here is 1 more crucial detail, all my research collaborator wants from each fitted BE is the factors/variables selected along with the name of the dataset, so the final output should look like the following for each row corresponding to the BE fitted to each dataset:

```
0-5-1-1, X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X9 X11 X13 X14 X22 X27
```

(n-n-n-n is how every csv is named)

I decided to start out by writing code to perform a BE Stepwise Regression on the 1st csv in the folder only via the following commands:

```
### BE Stepwise Regression run on dataset #1
dataset_1 <- read.csv("0-5-1-1.csv")

# assign the full model (all candidate predictors) to an object
all_IVs1 <- lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = dataset_1)

set.seed(50)     # to ensure replicability
BE_fit1 <- step(object = all_IVs1, direction = 'backward', 
       scope = formula(all_IVs1), trace = 0)

comma <- ","
cat(paste0(DS_name_list2[1], comma), names(BE_fit1[['coefficients']][-1]))
```

The last two lines are just for formatting the output in the way described above the code, I didn't include the code for DS_name_list2, but its name should make it self explanatory.

Anyway, as stated at the top, this code all works, it returns the following in the Console:

```
> cat(paste0(DS_name_list2[1], comma), names(BE_fit1[['coefficients']][-1]))
0-5-1-1, X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X9 X11 X13 X14 X22 X27
```

But I just cannot figure out how to repeat these steps on all N csvs in the folder using the lapply function! I have tried over half a dozen different variations of arguments by now, and the following is the red error message I have been getting most often:

```
Error in terms(object) : object 'i' not found
```

What does this mean and how would I avoid it by tweaking my code?

One example of the dozen plus variations I have tried was the following, this one results in the above error message:

```
set.seed(50)      # for reproducibility
BE_fits2 <- lapply(all_IVs_models2, function(i) {
  step(object = i[["coefficients"]], direction = 'backward', 
       scope = formula(all_IVs_model), trace = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution on the list of 18 files you showed earlier:

```r
names_list <- list.files("sample_obs2", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

step_function <- function(df_name) {
  df <- read.csv(df_name)
  all_IVs1 <- lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = df)
  BE_fit1 <- step(object = all_IVs1, direction = 'backward', 
       scope = formula(all_IVs1), trace = 0)
  names(BE_fit1[['coefficients']][-1])
}

mydata <- lapply(names_list, step_function) %>%
  setNames(names_list)

tibble::enframe(mydata)
```

**Output**

```r
# # A tibble: 18 × 2
#    name                    value     
#    <chr>                   <list>    
#  1 sample_obs2/0-5-1-1.csv <chr [11]>
#  2 sample_obs2/0-5-1-2.csv <chr [14]>
#  3 sample_obs2/0-5-1-3.csv <chr [9]> 
#  4 sample_obs2/0-5-2-1.csv <chr [9]> 
#  5 sample_obs2/0-5-2-2.csv <chr [5]> 
#  6 sample_obs2/0-5-2-3.csv <chr [9]> 
#  7 sample_obs2/0-5-3-1.csv <chr [10]>
#  8 sample_obs2/0-5-3-2.csv <chr [9]> 
#  9 sample_obs2/0-5-3-3.csv <chr [8]> 
# 10 sample_obs2/0-5-4-1.csv <chr [10]>
# 11 sample_obs2/0-5-4-2.csv <chr [11]>
# 12 sample_obs2/0-5-4-3.csv <chr [8]> 
# 13 sample_obs2/0-5-5-1.csv <chr [11]>
# 14 sample_obs2/0-5-5-2.csv <chr [10]>
# 15 sample_obs2/0-5-5-3.csv <chr [7]> 
# 16 sample_obs2/0-5-6-1.csv <chr [8]> 
# 17 sample_obs2/0-5-6-2.csv <chr [8]> 
# 18 sample_obs2/0-5-6-3.csv <chr [8]>
```

You can use `tidyr::unnest(value)` to view all of the names in each character vector. Or if you want to store the results in this format, use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` to preserve the nesting.

Comment: Very interesting approach! I was actually able to solve it last night using a different approach that combined two lapply functions within a single custom function as suggested to me on another question here. However, I might try your approach as well just in case it will be easier to write the final results to a txt or csv file than the way I did it.

Comment: I originally ended up going with another answer which involved a For Loop with two lapply functions in it, but the runtime was ridiculous, it took about 7 - 9 hours which I am sure is partly because R isn't optimized for For Loops. So, I am going to try this now to see how much runtime it cuts, but before I do, I need to know if 
Variables_selected_by_BE <- lapply(seq_along(BE_fits), 
                              \(i) names(coef(BE_fits[[i]])))
will still work to get just the coefficient estimates.

Comment: You would never put a seq_along inside an lapply to the best of my knowledge. 2 lapplys can always be combined into one. I recommend trying some simple lapplys on dummy data first so you get the hang of it, the fact that you are missing the `function` and still trying to index with `[[i]]` shows that a few weeks later you still do not understand that i in function(i) represents one unit of the iterable data, not an index. I advise sticking to my format.

Comment: I agree about the seq_along, the seq_along is in the initial parenthesis on the For Loop, not in the 2 lapplies which are the FUN of the For Loop. I understand what you said a few weeks ago and successfully applied it to my LASSO functions, but the way my code for my BE Stepwise Regressions currently is actually does run and it spits out everything correctly, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Thats really interesting, if there is a for loop that is the reason behind the slowness. For loops can almost always be subbed by lapply, which is faster.

Comment: Just go `Variables_selected_by_BE <- lapply(BE_fits, function (x) names(coef(x)))` for more speed. On second thought, ur prev solution works but is slow